# Why is the result empty when applying filter to mongoose-paginate in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Here is the code**
**It was working fine before I used same method in my other project but don't know what went wrong**
**Note: if I don't apply filter then result is not empty.**

```
async findAllCategories(req, res) {
    try {
      const { page = 1, perPage = 10, filter, sortField, sortDir } = req.query;
      const options = { page: parseInt(page, 10), limit: parseInt(perPage, 10) };
      const query = {};
      if (filter) {
            query.item = {
                $regex: filter
        }
      }
      if (sortField && sortDir) {
        options.sort = {
          [sortField]: sortDir
        }
      }
      console.log(query, options);
      const categories = await Category.paginate(query, options);
      return res.json(categories);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you add paginate to the schema?

Comment: Yes have a look. 
CategorySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
It was a simple mistake in query.item replaced it with query.name. It should be according to the field declared in model. I am still in learning phase.